# New to Android Development. What to DL?

Tags: android, development-environment

I've been searching and find lots of articles talking about Eclipse.  I saw one article that indicated I wanted Eclipse for RPC.  I saw another that indicated I should DL Eclipse for Java EEE.  But one said it was for Android 2.0 and the other didn't say one way or the other.

So I don't know which way to go.

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: This is kind of a crappy question and technically you're right, but it would be more helpful if you included some description or text from the link.

Comment: Too expand on what @R0MANARMY said: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)